# Using GridSearchCV gives an error with CalibratedClassifierCV in scikit-learn. GridSearchCV object has no attribute 'best_params_

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search

I use CalibratedClassifierCV with RandomForest and use GridSearch to determine the best parameters. However, when I use GridSearchCV to read back the best parameters it says  GridSearchCV object has no attribute 'best_params_'

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from classifiers import SVMClassification 
from sklearn.model_selection import  GridSearchCV
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as imbpipeline
        
pipeline=imbpipeline([ ('oversample', Sampling(random_state=444)),('rf', rf())])
paramgrid=[ {'rf__max_depth': [8,10], 'rf__n_estimators':[3,5]}]           
grid_search_rf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=paramgrid,cv=3)
rf_calibrated=CalibratedClassifierCV(grid_search_rf,cv=5, method="sigmoid")
rf_calibrated.fit(x_labelled,y_labelled)
print(rf_calibrated.base_estimator.best_params_)
```

## Output

> AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_params_'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are thinking that the CalibratedClassifierCV will fit the supplied estimator and then somehow enhance (calibrate) the output probabilities for that.

Thats partially correct.

What happens is:

- CalibratedClassifierCV will make a clone of the supplied estimator and then fit the data onto the clone. So you doing this

  ```
  rf_calibrated.base_estimator`
  ```

  will only return an unfitted estimator which don't have the `best_params_` attribute. `best_params_` is only available after fitting.

Checking `best_params_` from CalibratedClassifierCV will not make any sense, because it will divide the data into 5 parts (as you have done `cv=5`) in it and each fold is trained on a separate clone, so you may have multiple `best_params` in that depending on the data.

Comment: But Once I fit the data, it does create a single model which I use to predict. That model must have some fixed parameters( number of estimators,depth) for the base estimator, here Random Forest. I want to save these best parameters so that when I rerun  this estimator, I do not perform a grid search on parameters again.

Comment: @AMisra No. It has multiple `classifiers`. See the attribute `calibrated_classifiers_` in `CalibratedClassifierCV` documentation. When you call predict on it, it uses all these classifiers (which will have different parameter combinations based on fold), and then outputs some weighted average of probabilities from all these.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. If I do rf_calibrated.calibrated_classifiers_[0].base_estimator.best_params_,  then I can get the best estimator for one of the calibrated classifier.

Comment: @VivekKumar if you did: rf_calibrated=CalibratedClassifierCV(grid_search_rf.best_estimator,cv=5, method="sigmoid") not correct?